# linear interpolation $f(x)$ given $f(1)=1$ $f(5)=2$ and $f(7)=5$?

Tags: interpolation

linear interpolation if

$f(1)=1 $, 
$f(5)=2$,
$f(7)=5$.

What is $f(x)$?

I have tried with Lagrange but it doesn't work or maybe I am doing it wrong

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Could you add more context around your question? Where is it from? What have you tried? How do you usually solve problems like this?

Comment: Linear interpolation uses $2$ values. With $3$ values, you can only have a quadratic interpolation.

Comment: I get 0.59 with the quadratic interpolation also but I dont get any of the possible check-answers.